# Symfony workaround for using of protected methods

Tags: symfony

**Background**: symfony3

I have just stuck in the fact that `redirectToRoute` and `addFlash` methods in controller are protected in symfony. I have a separate class for action.

```
namespace AppBundle\Action;

class Base {

    public function __construct($controller) {
        $this->controller = $controller;
    }
}
```

As you can see base action class requires a controller. Basically it is logical because action class is part of a controller and should have access to all its methods. However I cannot call `$this->controller->addFlash` as it is protected. If it is protected then there might be some reason for it. I cannot find it. Can you please hint me how I can change my action class so that it could use controller methods.

The variant about extending action from a controller does not fit me as I have additional functionality in the main controller. It is configured in a proper way.

**Update**: my goal is to devide controller functionality by responsibility. I invented an action class. My end code look like following:

```
public function editAction() {
        $instance = new \AppBundle\Action\MyController\Edit($this);
        return $insance->run();
    }
```

In this case I keep controller clean and not verbose.

Comment: What is your plan, cause if your making a controller. Make a controller by extending symfony's controller class. If your not, your supposed to be working with the [service container](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html).

Comment: You could always add your own myAddFlash() and make it public.  But injecting a controller into a controller (even an action) is a bit bizarre.

Comment: @Cerad I do not inject a controller into a controller, but into an action (a separate class)

Comment: @JennevanderMeer I added an update

Comment: @Cerad I can duplicate methods, this is my temporary workaround. But it looks like not a right way.

Comment: I have also divided my controller actions into individual classes.  But just have them extend the Symfony controller class.  Works fine.  Action classes  are just controller classes with one method.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/service.html#base-controller-methods-and-their-service-replacements) is a [link](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/ControllerTrait.php) to Symfony Controller Trait, that you can duplicate, if you really want to work that way.

But since you are injecting a whole symfony controller into your own controllers, you will be better off with extending instead. Injection is used here for injecting separate service by their IDs.